# How to install gcc-multilib on ubuntu 22.04 in docker on M1 Mac

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I tried to install gcc-multilib in the ubuntu:22.04 docker container on my M1 Mac.
But I tried `$apt-get update && apt-get install gcc-multilib`. It showed the following error

```
Package gcc-multilib is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

I made some research and tried following solutions but none of them work.

1. Install new PPAs https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/issues/977#issuecomment-138402655

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to get it with `gcc-11-multilib` instead. I'm working from an ubuntu:22.04 docker image running on an Ubuntu 22.04 VM rather than Mac, but (I think?) the apt repositories would be the same.